# Is it okay to add a sympathy message or dedication to a victims of recent natural disaster to an academic acknowledgment?

Tags: publications, acknowledgement, dedication

So in my home country there has been a recent devastating natural disaster, I would like to add a message in the acknowledgments  to my current paper before submitting it regarding this. Would it be okay?

Comment: You would have to check the journal style guide. While theses often include personal acknowledgements, papers are usually restricted to contribution, collaboration and funding.

Comment: One issue is that it is unlikely that such a statement will not be particularly topical by the time the paper is accepted and finally published...

Comment: Is your paper relevant to Turkiye/earthquakes/disaster response? Or Syria.

Comment: I don't remember reading any paper with such dedication. So, it would be very unusual. 
Well, unless the paper is related to the recent earthquake somehow.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Perhaps if the paper is *generally* related -- if it's about earthquakes, or building construction, or disaster preparedness, or international cooperation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in the initial submission. Not everyone would agree, but the times aren't normal either. If it is a problem for a journal, according to their style guide and how rigidly they want to enforce it, they will tell you that and you can adjust. It is unlikely that it would affect the overall judgement of your work by reviewers or editors. You just might need to be flexible if you get pushback.

Note that very few papers get published exactly as first submitted.